# Listbox items always getting 0 count on server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have two `listboxs`, and two `buttons`. The `buttons` will transfer 1 item from `listbox1` to `listbox2`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnLeft").bind("click", function () {
        var options = $("[id*=listBoxRight] option:selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
            $(options[i]).remove();
            $("[id*=listBoxLeft]").append(opt);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("#btnRight").bind("click", function () {
        var options = $("[id*=listBoxLeft] option:selected");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
            $(options[i]).remove();
            $("[id*=listBoxRight]").append(opt);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This code is working and is transferring items from one another in the client side. My problem is when I get the value at the server side, I get 0 count.

Is it possible to bind the new items of `listbox2` using `jQuery`?

**EDIT**

I am using a user control:

The control is `ShutterUserControl` , and it contains two `listboxs`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your listbox runat server.

```
<select id="listboxRight" runat="server">
      <option>text1</option>
      <option>text2</option>
</select>
```

Then use following thing with Request.form. For that in your above JavaScript you need to use ClientID like `<%=listBoxRight.ClientID%>`.

Then you find that user control via two way one is with Request.Form

```
Request.Form["YourUserControlName$listboxRight"]
```

Another is

```
 var listBox = YourUserControlName.FindControl("listboxRight");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I know this will work on a regular listbox declared at the client side. But is it possible for a user control listbox ? See edit.

Comment: I can now see my dropdown using the second option you gave. But still 0 count.

Comment: try first option - With this you can get selected value - Request.Form["WebUserControl11$listboxRight"] it will give me text1 with my example.

Answer (score 0):

try `Request.Forms["controlName"]` to get the new values in the `dropdown` list.

Comment: I am using `Request.Form["usercontrol.listbox1"]` but it returned null value. I am using a user control.

Comment: The name of the control not `usercontrol.listbox1` look into the browser what is the control name then use that name.